# DependencyProperty.UnsetValue and DataContextChanged event

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I am wondering if DependencyProperty.UnsetValue fires DataContextChanged event when being set on DataContext property?

Its a bit confusing what MSDN says about this:

Specifies a static value that is used by the WPF property system rather than null to indicate that the property exists, but does not have its value set by the property system.

"Doesnt have its value set" so then when setting on DataContext the DataContextChanged event shall not trigger, right?

I wish I could test this somehow right now but I am on phone.

Thanks in advance guys, and in case its a duplicate please let me know so I remove the post before you downvote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `DataContext` explicitly to `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` fires the `DataContextChanged` event. `DependancyObject.SetValue` runs number of checks and logic while setting the DependancyProperty value, when we try to set `DataContext` to `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`, it sets it to `null` and raise event.

Comment: yup.. checked the DependancyObject implementation also, if value to be set is DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, it sets the default value which is null

Comment: Ohh thanks. Is there a new tool to reflect .net code? The only one I know is from red gate. But its expensiveeee. :) :) :)

Comment: yah i used to use that before my license expired.. :) now i rely on JetBrains "dotpeek"

Comment: awesome i didnt know about that. already excited to check it out. thanks nit